# window.print() does not execute more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I want to print to a printer more than once.
I have 2 DIVs one for "Order" and second for "Receipt", and a button "OrderAndPay". what I want is to print this two DIVs one after another.

This calls the function print() inside the plugin

```
orderPrint.KappaPrint();
receiptPrint.KappaPrint();
```

This function is in the plugin that creates the printable DIV

```
Print = function() {
        $(".printBlock").hide(); 
        printBlock.show(); 
        window.print(false);
        printBlock.hide();
    }
```

The problem is when I print one div it prints without any error.
But when I call the print for the 2 divs the print() makes an exception.

First exception: NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE.
Second exception: Some printing functionality is not currently available

Full Code:

```
Call The Print Function
"OrderAndPay": {
                    Text:KappaMainData.Constants.OrderAndPay,
                    OnClick : function(){
                        var itemsData = $("#ItemsDashBoard").KappaData();
                        if(itemsData === null) { return; }
                        var receiptData = {}, dat = {}, orderData = {};
                        dat = {"OrderOp":"Order", "Op":"Save", "SellOp":"OrderAndSell", "Data":itemsData};
                        var itemsSavedData = GetJsonAjax({Url:"Functions/order.php", Data:dat});
                        receiptData = GetRecieptData(itemsSavedData);

                        receiptPrint.Fill(receiptData);
                        orderData = GetOrderData(itemsSavedData);
                        orderPrint.Fill(orderData);
                        orderPrint.KappaPrint();
                        receiptPrint.KappaPrint(); //this one throws the exception
//always the second print throws exception
                    }
                },

Printing function
Print = function() {
        $(".printBlock").hide(); //class for all print blocks
        printBlock.show(); //current block
        window.print(); //Or:window.print(false);
        printBlock.hide();
    }
```

NOTE: I used css media print to control the visible things that I want to print.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @Pointy the exception is : Some printing functionality is not currently available.

Comment: Provide full code example